# Lisp error with elpy under Python 3

Tags: ipython, elpy

I've had my emacs (v. 25.1.1) working with elpy (1.13) under Python 2.7 for a while.  I decided to switch to Python 3 recently, and cannot get it to interact with emacs properly.  Normally, when I want to run a script in emacs I C-c C-c, which opens an ipython interpreter.  Since switching to Python3, the ipython interpreter still opens, but with problems.

1. I get the following backtrace error:

.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range "Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
Type \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

[6n[0m
[0m[J
" 427)
  string-match("" "Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) \nType \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n\nIPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.\n?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.\n%quickref -> Quick reference.\nhelp      -> Python's own help system.\nobject?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.\n\n[6n[0m
[0m[J
" 427)
  ansi-color-filter-apply("Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) \nType \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n\nIPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.\n?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.\n%quickref -> Quick reference.\nhelp      -> Python's own help system.\nobject?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.\n\n[?1l[6n[?2004h[?25l[?7l[0m
[0m[J
[?12l[?25h")
  python-shell-comint-watch-for-first-prompt-output-filter("Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) \nType \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n\nIPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.\n?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.\n%quickref -> Quick reference.\nhelp      -> Python's own help system.\nobject?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.\n\n[?1l[6n[?2004h[?25l[?7l[0m
[0m[J
[?12l[?25h")
  run-hook-with-args(python-shell-comint-watch-for-first-prompt-output-filter "Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) \nType \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n\nIPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.\n?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.\n%quickref -> Quick reference.\nhelp      -> Python's own help system.\nobject?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.\n\n[?1l[6n[?2004h[?25l[?7l[0m
[0m[J
[?12l[?25h")
  comint-output-filter(#<process Python> "Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) \nType \"copyright\", \"credits\" or \"license\" for more information.\n\nIPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.\n?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.\n%quickref -> Quick reference.\nhelp      -> Python's own help system.\nobject?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.\n\n[?1l[6n[?2004h[?25l[?7l[0m
[0m[J
[?12l[?25h")
```

2. The ipython interpreter looks "funky" as well.  Normally, line numbers would show up as:

.

```
In  [1]: 7/9

Out [1]: 0.77777777777777778

In  [2]:
```

However, I get something like this:

```
[6n[JIn [2]: [8D[8C7/9

[8D[JIn [2]: 7/9[11D

[JOut[2]: 0.7777777777777778

[6n[JIn [3]: [8D[8C
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why the ipython interpreter is so hosed.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in python-mode

Comment: Ok, I will submit a bug report.

Comment: I guess I am uncertain why this is a problem bug in python-mode as opposed to elpy.  Aren't these separate entities?